# Vertical Centering for multiple identical-height columns *without* flexbox

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Although flexbox is now pretty much the standard, and most users have the ability to use it, I wanted a robust old-school, backward-compatible solution for having multiple columns that are the same height, and whose contents are also vertically centered that does not rely on flexbox. It sounds easy, but those who are familiar with old-school html know that this is anything but straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the codepen I forked, with code created by gitter.im user @jdtdesigns: http://codepen.io/ihatecoding/pen/WwOyya

Here is the html he wrote:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="text-center">Header</h1>
  </header>
  <section class="main">
    <div class="left">
      <nav>
        <h3>Menu</h3>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Support</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Support</a>


      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas nulla quibusdam adipisci, enim libero ducimus, et? Porro ex in temporibus. Temporibus expedita aliquam, doloribus, perspiciatis in tempora soluta repellendus voluptatum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos et, quasi eligendi voluptatem praesentium repellendus! Cupiditate officia culpa placeat. Molestiae nulla laborum, est magni, cupiditate qui ullam eum aliquam consequuntur.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste consequuntur ea accusantium nemo amet. Sint, suscipit assumenda eos, exercitationem perferendis adipisci numquam sunt, nesciunt repellendus fugit vel ut saepe eligendi.</p>      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi distinctio illo asperiores, deserunt vitae unde, sint perferendis fugit aliquid similique earum impedit eaque nobis quibusdam blanditiis dolore? Nemo, iusto, quia!</p>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="ad">
        <h1>Ad</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="ad">
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
        <h1>Ad</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <h1 class="text-center">Footer</h1>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css he wrote:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.main > * {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 20%;
  background: #4385db;

  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
}

.center {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
}

header, footer {
  background: #9842a5;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav > * {
  display: block;
}
a {margin:20px;}
```